# Ignoring white space for a Regex match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to match 8 or more digits, the sequence of which can include spaces.

for example, all of the below would be valid matches.

```
12345678
1 2345678
12 3 45678
1234 5678
12 34567 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

At the moment I have `\d{8,}` but this will only capture a solid block of 8 or more digits.
`[\d\s]{8,}` will not work as I don't want white space to contribute to the count of chars captured.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Waayy later, but this really needs the correct answer on it, and a reason why.  Who knew this question could have such a complex answer, right?  Lol.  But there are plenty of considerations surrounding spacing in regex.

Firstly; Never put a space in a regex.  Doing so will make your regex unreadable, and unmaintainable.  Memories of using a mouse to highlight a space to ensure it was only one space comes to mind. This will break your regex:    , but this won't: [    ], because repetition in a character class is ignored.  And if you require an exact number of spaces, you can actually see that in a character class like so: `[ ]{3}`.  Versus accidents without the character class like so:   {3} <-- This is actually looking for 5 spaces, woops!

Second; Keep the Freespacing `(?x)` option in mind, which makes your regex commentable and free-spaceable.  You shouldn't fear that somebody using that option might break your regex because you decided to put random keyboard spaces in it.  Also, `(?x)` will **not** ignore the keyboard space when it's inside a character class like so: `[ ]`.  It is therefore safer to use character classes for your keyboard spaces.

Third; Try not to use `\s` in this scenario.  As Omaghosh points out, it also includes newlines (`\r` and `\n`).  The scenario you mentioned wouldn't seem to favor that.  However, also as Omaghosh points out, you may want more than just keyboard spaces.  So you can use either `[ ]`, `[\s-[\r\n]]`, or `[\f\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029\u0020]` depending on what you fancy.  The last two in those options are the same thing, but character class subtraction only works in .NET and a couple other weird flavors.

Fourth; This is a commonly over-built pattern: `(\s*...\s*)*`.  It doesn't make any sense.  It is the same as this: `(\s*\s*...)*` or this: `(\s*\s*\s*\s*...)*`.  Because the pattern is repeating.  The only argument against what I'm saying is that you'd be guaranteed to capture the spaces prior to the `...`.  But not once is that ever actually wanted.  Worst-case scenario, you might see this: `\s*(...\s*)*`

Omaghosh had the closest answer, but this is the shortest correct answer:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?:\d[ ]*){8,}").Groups[0].Value;
```

Or the following, if we take the question literally that the six options are in the same text on multiple lines:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?m)^(?:\d[ ]*){8,}$").Groups[0].Value;
```

Or the following, if it is part of a bigger regex and needs a group:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"...((?:\d[ ]*){8,})...").Groups[1].Value;
```

And feel free to replace the `[ ]` with a .NET Class Subtraction, or a Non-.NET explicit whitespace class:

```
@"(?:\d[\s-[\r\n]]*){8,}"
// Or . . .
@"(?:\d[\f\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029\u0020]*){8,}"
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 16):

```
(\d *){8,}
```

It matches eight or more occurrences of a digit followed by zero or more spaces. Change it to

```
( *\d *){8,}  #there is a space before first asterik
```

to match strings with spaces in the beginning. Or

```
(\s*\d\s*){8,}
```

to match tabs and other white space characters (that includes newlines too).

Finally, make it a non-capturing group with `?:`. Thus it becomes `(?:\s*\d\s*){8,}`

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d{8,}\s+)*\d{8,}
```

should work

Comment: Testing this in Expressio, it only matches `12345678` and none of the other examples.

Comment: @Greg B: I see what you mean. I was not sure.  To be honest, I dont think it is possible in 'vanilla' regex, but I'm sure there is a trick to handle it. Another option is to strip all the whitespace before applying the Regex.