# Regular expression: Match exact number of digits and ignore spaces

Tags: regex

I want to match exactly 8 digits, the sequence of digits can include spaces. For example, all of the following are valid.

```
'12345678'
' 12 345678'
'12345678    '
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  '
'123 456 78'
```

I have read this but the answer also matches more than 8 digits. [Ignoring white space for a Regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279943/ignoring-white-space-for-a-regex-match)

Comment: `\s*(\d\s*){8}`. By the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have much harder logic behind this question and I try to ask in a most simplest way. Of course, I try many combinations before asking, but I seems to miss the most simple one.

Comment: If you have *"much harder logic"* behind the question, you should explain it, your approach may be wrong and the answers will be more interesting. Explain what you are trying to do and show what you have already done.

Comment: In most cases you will need to add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to your string.

Comment: @wdetac Then [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) should bring more light over the problem of repeating the pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks I will explain more next time. This time I got the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jaroslaw Pawlak said:

```
var str = "123 456 78 ";
var test = /^\s*(\d\s*){8}$/.test(str);
console.log(test); // true
```

Comment: That will return true for any number of digits greater or equal to 8. Should be /^\s*(\d\s*){8}$/. See https://jsfiddle.net/4y8ozb5c/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex :

```
(\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d)
```

or :

```
((\d\s*){7}\d)
```

Comment: Thanks but your answer is not correct, but I got the answer from the idea.